# Is "being raised getting trained" a correct expression?

Tags: paraphrasing

I have a simple question about my phrasing a thought. The exemplary sentence I would say is as follows:

> He was raised getting trained about restaurant management.

However, as I googled "raised getting trained" part, it yielded only 4-5 results. How would you paraphrase this sentence in a most native sounding way?

Comment: what are you trying to say? That his parents trained him in hotel management as he was growing up?

Comment: Change the job into anything...

Comment: We are **trained *in* something** not *about*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say things like this,

> His father was a chef, and he was **brought up in** the restaurant
>   business.

The implicit idea is pretty close to your more explicit "raised *getting trained*", which is not idiomatic.

You could substitute "raised" for "brought up" there: "He was raised in the restaurant business."

You could make it more colorful and more informal, expressing the idea that he was very familiar with the food though not necessarily formally trained in its preparation:

> His parents ran a restaurant, and he **grew up around** kebabs.
>
> His parents had a ranch, and he grew up around livestock.

Here's one with a participle:

> His mom was an eye-doctor and he **grew up listening** to talk of corneas and vitreous humor.

And here's one that comes closer to the passive:

> His parents were pedants, and he was raised *having his every grammatical error corrected* by the one, or the other, or by the both of them.

Answer (score 1):

> raised

has the meaning "to grow up" as in

> born and raised

The sentences

> He was raised in restaurant management.
>   He was raised being trained in restaurant management.

has the meaning that the person's family is in the restaurant business and the person grew up in the family business.

If you wanted to say they learned the restaurant business as their first job, on might say

> He was trained in the restaurant management.
>   He started out being trained in restaurant management.

Comment: So is "trained about" not right? Because, actually my full expression should be about meat and kebabs not exactly restaurant management. The father trains him about meat and kebabs... However I'm not sure how to phrase it for the native ears.

Comment: @Reactor4 you _train_ someone _in_ something, but you _teach_ someone _about_ something. You may want to consider using a different verb :)

Comment: @Reactor4 It might be better to use "His father taught him about meat and kebabs.", "He was trained in cooking meats."